# Can not join bash array when it contains dynamically formed strings

Tags: bash

I need to generate SQL statement using bash

This code works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
STRINGS+=("( host = '.example.com' AND name = 'auth.sid' )")
STRINGS+=("( host = '.site.example.test' AND name = 'key' )")

joinByString() {
  local separator="$1"
  shift
  local first="$1"
  shift
  printf "%s" "$first" "${@/#/$separator}"
}

joinByString ' OR ' "${STRINGS[@]}"
```

it prints `( host = '.example.com' AND name = 'auth.sid' ) OR ( host = '.site.example.test' AND name = 'key' )`

But if `STRINGS` array is dynamic - it does not work:

```
MAIN_COOKIES=$(cat <<EOF
.example.com:auth.sid
.site.example.test:key
EOF
)

joinByString() {
  local separator="$1"
  shift
  local first="$1"
  shift
  printf "%s" "$first" "${@/#/$separator}"
}

declare -a andConditions
while read -r line
do
  IFS=':' read -r -a array <<< "$line"
  cookie_name="${array[1]}"
  cookie_hostname="${array[0]}"
  and_condition="( host = '${cookie_hostname}' AND name = '${cookie_name}' )"
  andConditions+=($and_condition)
done < <(echo "${MAIN_COOKIES}")
joinByString ' OR ' "${andConditions[@]}"
```

prints `( OR host OR = OR '.example.com' OR AND OR name OR = OR 'auth.sid' OR ) OR ( OR host OR = OR '.site.example.test' OR AND OR name OR = OR 'key' OR )` - so `joinByString` function adds `$separator` near every space character.

Comment: You forgot the quotes in `andConditions+=("$and_condition")`

Comment: `< <(echo ${MAIN_COOKIES}")` just `<<<"${MAIN_COOKIES}"` | `while read -r line
do
  IFS=':' read -r -a array`? Just `while IFS=: read -r -a array; do`